# why doesn't validating input on eventListener work?

Tags: reactjs, addeventlistener

Could you help me to make this sandbox work?
I miss something.

When the length of the password or login is more than 3, I'd like to see "GOOD" instead of "FAIL" close to the input.

here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-bogdan-5604u?file=/src/App.js

Thanks!

Comment: The relevant code should be in the question not off site.

Comment: Aside from that, its a bit of a red flag that you're using an event listener for react inputs. Just put that logic in the change handler function, they're already controlled inputs.

Comment: already tried, it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems, but they all come from the same root - state updates to not take place immediately.

Problem one is that you cannot use the updated state right after calling `setState`. This is causing your validation logic to execute using the form values from the **previous** render.

Problem two is that if you call a state updater function twice in a row, it will only use the last value. So in your validation logic, you call `setFormError` once based on the value of `login`, and once based on the value of `password`. This means the value determined by the `login` logic will never be used.

I've written an example of a few ways you can write this correctly.

Example one as a function called on each input change:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const MyInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <input {...props} style={{ border: "1px solid red", outline: "none" }} />
  );
};

const Example = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    login: "",
    password: ""
  });
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState({
    isValidLogin: "FAIL",
    isValidPassword: "FAIL"
  });

  const handleValidateForm = (newForm) => {
    let newValid = {...formError}; // Use a new object so we only update state once
    
    if (newForm.login.length > 3) {
      newValid.isValidLogin = "GOOD"
    } else {
      newValid.isValidLogin = "FAIL"
    }
    if (newForm.password.length > 3) {
      newValid.isValidPassword = "GOOD"
    } else {
      newValid.isValidPassword = "FAIL"
    }
    
    setFormError(newValid);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    
    const newForm = {...form, [name]: value}; // Set to new object

    setForm(newForm);
    
    handleValidateForm(newForm); // Send the new object so its up-to-date
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <MyInput type="text" name="login" onChange={onChange} />{" "}
        {formError.isValidLogin}
        <br />
        <MyInput type="text" name="password" onChange={onChange} />{" "}
        {formError.isValidPassword}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The other approach would be to move the validation into a `useEffect`:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const MyInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <input {...props} style={{ border: "1px solid red", outline: "none" }} />
  );
};

const Example = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    login: "",
    password: ""
  });
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState({
    isValidLogin: "FAIL",
    isValidPassword: "FAIL"
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let newValid = {...formError}; // Use a new object so we only update state once
    
    if (form.login.length > 3) {
      newValid.isValidLogin = "GOOD"
    } else {
      newValid.isValidLogin = "FAIL"
    }
    if (form.password.length > 3) {
      newValid.isValidPassword = "GOOD"
    } else {
      newValid.isValidPassword = "FAIL"
    }
    
    setFormError(newValid);
  }, [form]); // Runs every time the form changes

  const onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    
    setForm({...form, [name]: value});
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <MyInput type="text" name="login" onChange={onChange} />{" "}
        {formError.isValidLogin}
        <br />
        <MyInput type="text" name="password" onChange={onChange} />{" "}
        {formError.isValidPassword}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

It has the same effect, so its up to you which pattern you prefer.